# Reassign Ctrl and Alt keys - xmodmap 'BadValue' error

Tags: debian, x11, xorg, keyboard, xmodmap

I am attempting to remap my keyboard in order to make emacs usable. My ergonomic keyboard puts its single Control key in an isolated 4-key island way off to the left.

The OS is Debian squeeze.

Here are the lines I am attempting to feed to `xmodmap`, I place them into a file ~/.Xmodmap:

```
clear Control
clear Mod1
! The Alt keys are labled 'Option' on my keyboard, 
! using xev shows them to send Alt_L and Alt_R keysym's respectively 
keysym Alt_L = Control_L
keysym Alt_R = Control_R
! The Super_L and Super_R keys are the Windows keys
keysym Super_L = Alt_L
keysym Super_R = Alt_R
add Control = Control_L Control_R
add Mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R
```

My goal is to make my Option (a.k.a. <kbd>Alt</kbd>) keys behave like Control keys, and to get my Windows (a.k.a. Super) keys to behave like <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Here are the keycodes and keysms output by xev for the keys in question.  Note, my keyboard  (a Goldtouch ergonomic keyboard) has only one control key.

```
keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L)
keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L)
keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L)
keycode 134 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R)
keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R)
```

Here is what xev displays while running `xmodmap .Xmodmap`

```
MappingNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 204, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 64, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 108, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 206, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 133, count 1

MappingNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 134, count 1
```

And here is the error returned by `xmodmap`:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
Value in failed request:  0x17
Serial number of failed request:  17
Current serial number in output stream:  17
```

any suggestions about how I can resolve this?

Comment: On what operating system and version? What broad type of keyboard (PC/Mac/Sun/...)? Try runnning `xev` in a terminal, then `xmodmap` in another terminal. You should see some `MappingNotify` stanzas from `xev`, add them to your question. Also, in the `xev` window, press the various keys involved and tell us what keycode and keysym they correspond to (the “keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L)” part of the xev output).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has already been reported as [Debian bug #564327](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=564327), [Debian bug #565279](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=565279), [Ubuntu bug #524774](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/524774), and [FreeDesktop bug 20145](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20145). There is a source patch attached to the FreeDesktop bug discussion. There are several workaround proposals in the Ubuntu bug discussion, in particular [a `.Xmodmap` workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/524774/comments/17).

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the workaround linked by Giles, this is what worked for me:

```
clear Mod1
clear Mod4

keycode 204 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol
keycode 206 = NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol

keycode 64 = Control_L Control_L Control_L Control_L
keycode 133 = Alt_L Alt_L Alt_L Alt_L
keycode 134 = Alt_R Alt_R Alt_R Alt_R
keycode 108 = Control_R Control_R Control_R Control_R

add Control = Control_L Control_R
add Mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R
```

My Option keys now function like Control keys and my Windows Keys like Alt keys.

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises when you try to add a keysym to a modifier which is already added to another modifier key. It is vital to know, that if you add a keysym to a modifier all other keysyms that companion the keysym in case are added also as to that modifier.

For example:

```
clear mod5
add mod5    = ISO_Level3_Shift Mode_switch
```

can result in

```
mod5        backslash (0x33),  Caps_Lock (0x42),  ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

because you have something like

```
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
```

in your ~/.Xmodmap (View the current keycode to keysym mapping via `xmodmap -pke`)

which will produce the BadValue error in question when you also try to do something like

```
add lock    = Caps_Lock
```

because Caps_Lock is already added to the mod5 modifier.

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution to your problem although it doesn't really answer your question. Edit xorg.conf, inserting the following into Section "InputDevice":

```
 Option "XkbOptions" "ctrl:swapcaps"
```