# Set the key for spanish eñe letter

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

How can I map the spanish eñe letter to a key combination? What application is suitable for this purpose (`xmodmap`, `xbindkeys`, ...)?

When I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>, it should type `ñ`

When I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, it should type `Ñ`

I'd like to do this without switching keyboard layouts; I want to use only the English keyboard layout.

Comment: Do you want Caps Lock to also have the caps lock effect? Do you also have an `AltGr` key (i.e. a key that makes some character keys insert a different character, never mind that it's the right Alt key or not)?

Comment: Caps Lock can lose its effect. Or it can be mapped to Fn key + n or something what is comfortable to press and not colliding (Alt is colliding and Win key is already in use).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer explains how to set this up with xmodmap. Put the configuration snippets below in `~/.Xmodmap`, and run `xmodmap <~/.Xmodmap` to apply them. Depending on your distribution and your setup, `~/.Xmodmap` may be loaded automatically when you log in, or you may need to call `xmodmap` explicitly from `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`, or you may need to configure your desktop environment to apply `~/.Xmodmap`.

X has a keysym (i.e. an abstract key name) called `Mode_switch`. On most keyboard mappings for latin-script languages other than US, this keysym is bound to the key labeled <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, which replaces the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. You can choose to map `Mode_switch` to a different key such as <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. On a PC keyboard, the keycode (what the hardware sends) for <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is 66, so change its binding to `Mode_switch`, and remove the caps lock modifier from it:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
clear Lock
```

You also need to associate a modifier with `Mode_switch`. There are 5 custom modifiers, `Mod1` through `Mod5`; any will do, but there has to be one. Run `xmodmap -pm` to see what modifiers are in use, and pick one of the 5 that isn't, then add a line like this to your `.Xmodmap`:

```
add Mod3 = Mode_switch
```

In an xmodmap key specification, the character sent by the key with `Mode_switch` is in the third column after the `=` sign, and with `Mode_switch`+`Shift` in the fourth column. (The first two columns are for the key with no modifiers and with `Shift`.) You can use a `keysym` directive to rebind the key that now sends `n` regardless of its keycode:

```
keysym n = n N ntilde Ntilde
```

The names on the right are in fact keysym names. You can find a list of these in
`/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`, e.g. the line `#define XK_Ntilde 0x00d1` means there's a keysym called `Ntilde` that corresponds to Unicode character U+00D1. There are characters that don't have a keysym name; you can use the unicode number instead.

```
! U+2030 is PER MILLE SIGN, U+2031 is PER TEN THOUSAND SIGN
keysym 5 = 5 percent U2030 U2031
```

Note that if you're shifting modifiers around on systems of ~2009–2011 vintage, you might run into an [`X_SetModifierMapping` bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/reassign-ctl-and-alt-keys-xmodmap-error). Often, but not always, using `clear Lock` will work around the bug.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks... very interesting...  *`keysym n =`* and *`keycode 57 =`*, do the same thing, but I suppose that using `keysym` is more portable... another mystery demystified...  (and it is easy to toggle it via a hotkey, to quickly get access the caps-lock again) ...

Comment: This worked only for a while. After a few sentences it swapped n with ntilde. So, I have to press mod_switch + n to type n and n to type ntilde. It happened already three times, so I believe there is something wrong with this mod_switch.

Comment: @xralf: Did you add `clear Lock`? (I forgot it in my original answer.)

Comment: @Gilles Actually I used rather `keycode 94 = Mode_switch` without `clear lock`.

Comment: @xralf: If you rebound a key that isn't `CapsLock`, you don't need the `clear Lock` part. But you need another part I'd forgotten (sorry): there must be a modifier associated with `Mode_switch`. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you. I added `add Mod3 = Mode_switch` after `keycode 94 = Mode_switch` and will test it. Could you please tell me where you learned about xmodmap to avoid my other questions? I searched for some tutorials but nowhere was good explanation of the principles and basic concepts like mod1..mod5, mod_switch etc. and how to utilize it effectively.

Comment: @xralf: I don't remember, it was last century! There's a GUI application `xkeycaps` that generates a `.Xmodmap` file, my `.Xmodmap` is ultimately derived from that. And you can at least find examples on the web or through `locate xmodmap`.

Comment: The new settings ended with error message `X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
`

Comment: @xralf: I'd have to see your `.Xmodmap` file for a better diagnosis, but I suspect you're affected by [this issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4485). Try [the cited workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/524774/comments/17).

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/601810/) is my xmodmap file.

Comment: @xralf: So yes, it looks like you're hit by that bug. Try using `clear Lock` instead of `remove`, or the other changes suggested in the workaround.

Comment: I tried the workaround but without success. I have found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/524774) and [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=22994) the suggestion for patch but don't know how to use it. Is it suitable to ask another question for it?

Comment: @xralf: If you can't make it work with the [existing question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4485) on that topic, then yes, ask another question.

Comment: I will accept it because it's fault of bug. I heard that `xkb` is better than `xmodmap` so I will rather try `xkb` than solving this bug. Please warn readers about this bug in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what you want, but instead of `Caps Lock` you can use `AltGr`:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>   producing `ñ`

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>   producing `Ñ`

To get that with `xmodmap` you must know the keycode which produces the `N`. This can be done with:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep "n N n N"
```

where you may get something like: `keycode  57 = n N n N n N`. This means that the keycode `57` represents the <kbd>n</kbd> key.

Then, you remap this keycode, to produce the `ñ` and `Ñ` with:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  57 = n N n N ntilde Ntilde"
```

(with this command, the fifth position after the `=` is produced when you type that key in combination with `AltGr`, and the sixth position when `AltGr` and `Shift` are pressed together).

If this woks, [you can make it to run automatically after login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11604/run-xmodmap-commands-after-login).

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work. When I press `AltGr + n` it prints `:`. And it would be better to map it with caps lock or other key because AltGr would conflict in many applications.

Comment: You show 6 values: `n N n N n N` .. I only get **4** values in the output from `xmodmap` (Ubuntu) and it works when I set the 3rd and 4th values, but fails on 5th and 6th... You even mention the words "fitth" and "sixth" ... Is there a difference in implementation of `xmodmap` from one distro to another?

Comment: @fred: I use ubuntu in two different machines and in both of them I get six values for that command... I don't know why the difference with you. May be it doesn't depend on the distribution but it does according to other circumstances or settings...

Comment: @xralf: Are your `Alt` and `AltGr` keys identical in behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having caps lock not work anymore as a 'caps lock' key, you can remap it to an 'altgr-like' status with `xmodmap -e 'keysym Caps_Lock = ISO_Level3_Shift'`.

Comment: I've never used an AltGr "enabled" keyboard before, but I think that simply setting Caps-Lock to be AlgGr isn't enough... all relevant keys would need to be set to act differntly when AlgGr is pressed... A standard US keyboard mapping is not aware of anything other than ASCII characters.

Comment: Well, you would also have to do the mapping mentioned in the other answer. I thought that would go without saying.